# Dash layout is a mystery - I feel like I am programming in Lisp

Tags: layout, plotly-dash

I have seen [this](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started) documentation, and I still don't understand how manipulate the dash layout.

I initialize `dash` like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
today = datetime.today()

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

I want to arrange a dash `layout` so that there is:

```
A header on the very top
A dropdown, date picker, and another drop down, all on the same row without pusing into the header
A Table, that is a fixed height and has a scroll bar (not all data displayed have to scroll)
A Graph at the end
```

**How do I achieve this**:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+             Header               +
+ dropdown1 datepicker dropdown2   +
+ Table (extends all the way right)+
+ Graph (extends all the way right)+
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Right now, the display is such that each `component` is stacked one on to of the other, with the `dropdown` extending all the way from left to right, the `datepicker` is of limited size, the table and `graph` extending from left to right.

**EDIT 1**

The solution below by Yaakov solves several of my problems, i.e., the components are now a reasonable size, and the table is no longer hoging the entire page below the components.

But one problem remains, the components, with the exception of the table, are pushing up into the header, and they are stacked one on top of the other and not side-by-side. This is my dash code:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.css.config.serve_locally = False
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.H1(
            'Header Title',
            style={'color': 'orange', 'text-align': 'center'},     
        ),

    html.Div([ 
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown1',
        options=[
            {'label': 'SPX', 'value': 'SPX'},
            {'label': 'AAPL', 'value': 'AAPL'},
            {'label': 'IBM', 'value': 'IBM'}
        ],
        value='SPX',
        style = {'display':'blocl', 'width':'33%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
    )],
    ),
    html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerSingle(
        id='my-date-picker-single',
        min_date_allowed=dt(2004, 1, 2),
        max_date_allowed=today,
        date=today 
    ),
      html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-single')
    ],
    ),
    html.Div([ 
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown2',
        options=[
            {'label': '10:00', 'value': '10:00:00'},
            {'label': '10:30', 'value': '10:30:00'},
            {'label': '11:00', 'value': '11:00:00'},
            {'label': '11:30', 'value': '11:30:00'},
            {'label': '12:00', 'value': '12:00:00'},
            {'label': '12:30', 'value': '12:30:00'},
            {'label': '13:00', 'value': '13:00:00'},
            {'label': '13:30', 'value': '13:30:00'},
            {'label': '14:00', 'value': '14:00:00'},
            {'label': '14:30', 'value': '14:30:00'},
            {'label': '15:00', 'value': '15:00:00'}
        ],
        style = {'display':'blocl', 'width':'33%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
    )],
    ),
    html.Div([
     dash_table.DataTable(
          id='datatable-interactivity',
          columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
          #fixed_rows={ 'headers': True, 'data': 0 },
          data=df.to_dict("rows"),
          page_current=0,
          page_size=0,
          page_action='custom',
          style_cell_conditional=[
        {'if': {'column_id': 'pSpot'},
         'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'quoteDatetime'},
         'width': '175px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingSymbol'},
         'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'expiration'},
         'width': '175px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'strike'},
         'width': '60px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'optionType'},
         'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'bid'},
         'width': '100px'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'ask'},
         'width': '100px'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingBid'},
         'width': '130px',  'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingAsk'},
         'width': '130px',  'textAlign': 'center'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'iv'},
         'width': '85px'},
        {'if': {'column_id': 'id'},
         'width': '155px'},
        ],
        style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'column_id': 'optionType',
                'filter_query': '{optionType} eq C'
                },
            'backgroundColor': '#3D9970',
            'color': 'white',
        }
        ],
        style_header={
          'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
          'fontWeight': 'bold'
        },
    ),

    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')

    ],
    style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'height': '50vh'}
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**EDIT 2**

This almost works. The controls are side-by-side. They also don't intrude on the Header. However, when I click on any of the components that are side-by-side, I can't see the choices, and there is weird behavior in that they collapse and go back to being stacked one on top of the other (and ghost images where they were):

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        html.H1(
                'Header Title',
                style={'color': 'orange', 'text-align': 'center'},     
        )
    ),

    html.Div([ 
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown1',
            options=[
                {'label': 'SPX', 'value': 'SPX'},
                {'label': 'AAPL', 'value': 'AAPL'},
                {'label': 'IBM', 'value': 'IBM'}
            ],
            value='SPX',
            style = {'display':'blocl', 'width':'33%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
        ),

        dcc.DatePickerSingle(
            id='my-date-picker-single',
            min_date_allowed=dt(2004, 1, 2),
            max_date_allowed=today,
            date=today 
        ),

        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown2',
            options=[
                {'label': '10:00', 'value': '10:00:00'},
                {'label': '10:30', 'value': '10:30:00'},
                {'label': '11:00', 'value': '11:00:00'},
                {'label': '11:30', 'value': '11:30:00'},
                {'label': '12:00', 'value': '12:00:00'},
                {'label': '12:30', 'value': '12:30:00'},
                {'label': '13:00', 'value': '13:00:00'},
                {'label': '13:30', 'value': '13:30:00'},
                {'label': '14:00', 'value': '14:00:00'},
                {'label': '14:30', 'value': '14:30:00'},
                {'label': '15:00', 'value': '15:00:00'}
            ],
            style = {'display':'blocl', 'width':'33%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
        )
    ], style={'columnCount': 3}
    ),

    html.Div([
     dash_table.DataTable(
          id='datatable-interactivity',
          columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
          #fixed_rows={ 'headers': True, 'data': 0 },
          data=df.to_dict("rows"),
          page_current=0,
          page_size=0,
          page_action='custom',
          style_cell_conditional=[
            {'if': {'column_id': 'pSpot'},
            'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'quoteDatetime'},
            'width': '175px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingSymbol'},
            'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'expiration'},
            'width': '175px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'strike'},
            'width': '60px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'optionType'},
            'width': '50px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'bid'},
            'width': '100px'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'ask'},
            'width': '100px'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingBid'},
            'width': '130px',  'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'underlyingAsk'},
            'width': '130px',  'textAlign': 'center'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'iv'},
            'width': '85px'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'id'},
            'width': '155px'},
            ],
            style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'column_id': 'optionType',
                    'filter_query': '{optionType} eq C'
                    },
                'backgroundColor': '#3D9970',
                'color': 'white',
            }
        ],
        style_header={
          'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
          'fontWeight': 'bold'
        },
    ),

    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')

    ],
    style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'height': '50vh'}
    )
])
```

**EDIT 3**

Changing

`'display' : 'inline-block'`

in EDIT 2 above almost works! But when I click on the components, instead of the dropdown going over the table, the table underneath gets moved down to allow the display of the choices, then everything snaps back after the dropdown selection is made.

**EDIT 4**

Table is not necessary, any control at the bottom works:

```
,
dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-2',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'font': {
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

**EDIT 5**

Complete example with a graph instead of table. Makes no difference:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.css.config.serve_locally = False
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

#for css in external_css:
#    app.css.append_css({"external_url": css})

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

app.layout = html.Div(children = [
    html.Div(
        html.H1(
                'Header Title',
                style={'color': 'orange', 'text-align': 'center'},     
        )
    ),

    html.Div([ 
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown1',
            options=[
                {'label': 'SPX', 'value': 'SPX'},
                {'label': 'AAPL', 'value': 'AAPL'},
                {'label': 'IBM', 'value': 'IBM'}
            ],
            value='SPX',
            style = {'display':'inline-block', 'width':'32%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
        ),

        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown2',
            options=[
                {'label': '10:00', 'value': '10:00:00'},
                {'label': '10:30', 'value': '10:30:00'},
                {'label': '11:00', 'value': '11:00:00'},
                {'label': '11:30', 'value': '11:30:00'},
                {'label': '12:00', 'value': '12:00:00'},
                {'label': '12:30', 'value': '12:30:00'},
                {'label': '13:00', 'value': '13:00:00'},
                {'label': '13:30', 'value': '13:30:00'},
                {'label': '14:00', 'value': '14:00:00'},
                {'label': '14:30', 'value': '14:30:00'},
                {'label': '15:00', 'value': '15:00:00'}
            ],
            value='15:00',
            style = {'display':'inline-block', 'width':'32%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
        ),

        dcc.DatePickerSingle(
            id='my-date-picker-single',
            min_date_allowed=dt(2004, 1, 2),
            max_date_allowed=today,
            date=today 
        ),

    ], style={'columnCount': 3}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-2',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'MontrÃ©al'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'font': {
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            }
        }
    )
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Clarify in your code `dt` – also, provide a replicable instance for `df`

Comment: Yaakov, see OP for dt. Also, you can put anything you want in the table, for example, these random numbers for one row, df = 1, 2017-06-01T11:00:00,SPX,
2017-06-16T11:00:00,2420,C,11.7,12.5,2414.93,2415.65,8.17,0

Comment: You can put anything instead of table, for example, look at Edit 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust this in the `style` parameter of each individual `html` or `dcc` components upon instantiation. You can define in your `app.py` file by including in the instantiation as such:

```
html.Div(
  id='dropdown1',
  children='this is a dropdown',
  style = {'display':'blocl', 'width':'33%', 'margin-left':'0', 'margin-right':'0'}
)
```

For your table, you can set `y-overflow` to `scroll` and your height to `50vh` (50% of the view height):

```
style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'height': '50vh'}
```

**EDIT:**

*(In response to edit 4)* Make the following changes to the *style* of your html objects to correct the wild overflowing:

```
    html.Div(
        children = [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown1',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'SPX', 'value': 'SPX'},
                    {'label': 'AAPL', 'value': 'AAPL'},
                    {'label': 'IBM', 'value': 'IBM'}
                ],
                value='SPX',
                style = {'width':'30%', 'margin':'0 0 0'}
            ),

            dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                id='my-date-picker-single',
                # min_date_allowed=dt(2004, 1, 2),
                # max_date_allowed=today,
                # date=today
                style = {'width':'30%', 'margin':'0 0 0'}
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown2',
                options=[
                    {'label': '10:00', 'value': '10:00:00'},
                    {'label': '10:30', 'value': '10:30:00'},
                    # And so on....
                ],
                style = {'width':'30%', 'margin':'0 0 0'}
            )
        ],
    # Link to CSS styles https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
    style={'display':'flex', 'flex-direction': 'row'}
    ),
```

Comment: Your suggestion solved several problems, but for some reason the components push up into the header area. See EDIT 1 in OP for code section that shows how I am laying out.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? (perhaps as a link in a comment – you can delete shortly after. I just want to "see" without running a dash server.) @Ivan

Comment: Nevermind @Ivan – I'm going to run your code. It's excellently provided – clean and clear. :)

Comment: Yaakov, see Edit 2 and Edit 3!

Comment: That works! Never in a million years would i have figured this out. Thanks.

Comment: BTW Yaakov, if I want to add say the graph in EDIT 5 underneath the table, it doesn't look right. What style do I give the table and the graph so that they live nice together? Should I ask a new question on SO?

Comment: Yes, better ask a new Q so that future readers don't melt their eyes. 